# Joomla Core Bootstrap is not working Joomla 3.0 site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla3.0

i am trying implement Bootstrap for in my front end view (Component).

But it's not working for me.

Path component/com_helloworld/views/helloworlds/tmpl/default.php

Here is the code

```
<?php JHtml::_('behavior.framework'); ?>

<div class="container">
```

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Adress</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Lee</td>
            <td>johnlee@gmail.com.com</td>
            <td>899888777887</td>
            <td>SNR</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `JHtml::_('behavior.framework');` is for the deprecated Mootools framework.

Try `JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');` instead.

Note that this is for the javascript framework only.
If you want the css, try:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

(NB There may be tidier ways to add that.)